# Variable $varname does not appear in any graphQL query

Tags: graphql, insomnia

I'm trying to reference a variable in my graphql query. I thought this was going to be straightforward but I'm obviously missing something. Can someone educate me on this?

```
mutation {
    requestAccessToken(
        input: {
            grant_type: CLIENT_CREDENTIALS
            client_id: $clientId
            client_secret: $clientSecret
        }
    ) {
        access_token
    }
}
```

Variables

```
{
    "clientId": "1234",
    "clientSecret": "sekeret"
}
```

I tried through insomnia and GraphQL playground and the results are the same.
The program tells me there's no variables defined, and where I defined them it tells me they're not being used.

I made the variables basic strings to rule out any formatting weirdness with getting them out of my environment and I get the same issue.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwya7.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should accept the variable in mutation header just like this,

```
    mutation($clientId: Int!,$clientSecret: String!) {
        requestAccessToken(
            input: {
                grant_type: CLIENT_CREDENTIALS
                client_id: $clientId
                client_secret: $clientSecret
            }
        ) {
            access_token
        }
}
```